# TrainSet Practice Problem from CodeChef

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, memory-optimization

A dataset consisting of N items. Each item is a pair of a word and a boolean denoting whether the given word is a spam word or not.

There shouldn't be a word included in the training set that's marked both as spam and not-spam. For example item `{"fck", 1}`, and item `{"fck, 0"}` can't be present in the training set, because first item says the word `"fck"` is a spam, whereas the second item says it is not, which is a contradiction.

Your task is to select the maximum number of items in the training set.

Note that same pair of `{word, bool}` can appear multiple times in input. The training set can also contain the same pair multiple times.

Question link is [here](https://www.codechef.com/problems/TRAINSET).

*What I have done so far:*

- Grouped given pair by word and taken count of spam and not-spam of
  each group.
- Finally, taken `max` count of each group and taken `sum` of this
  values.

**Code:**

```
from itertools import groupby
from collections import Counter

t = int(input())
for _ in range(t):
    n = int(input())
    data_set = sorted([tuple(map(str, input().split())) for __ in range(n)])
    print(sum(max(Counter(element[1]).values()) for element in groupby(data_set, key=lambda x:x[0])))
```

My code is working fine. Is my solution is efficient? If not please explain an efficient algorithm.

What is the time complexity of my algorithm?

Is it `O(N)`?

**Example Input:**

```
3
3
abc 0
abc 1
efg 1
7
fck 1
fck 0
fck 1
body 0
body 0
body 0
ram 0
5
vv 1
vv 0
vv 0
vv 1
vv 1
```

**Example Output:**

```
2
6
3
```

**Constraints:**

- 1≤T≤10
- 1≤N≤25,000
- 1≤|wi|≤5 for each valid i
- 0≤si≤1 for each valid i
- w1,w2,…,wN contain only lowercase English letters

**Edit-1:**

To take input from file for testing,

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for _ in range(int(f.readline())):
        n = int(f.readline())
        data_set = [tuple(map(str, f.readline().replace('\n','').split())) for __ in range(n)]

        print(data_set) 
        # your logic here
 # Output:
 # [('abc', '0'), ('abc', '1'), ('efg', '1')]
 # [('fck', '1'), ('fck', '0'), ('fck', '1'), ('body', '0'), ('body', '0'), ('body', '0'), ('ram', '0')]
 # [('vv', '1'), ('vv', '0'), ('vv', '0'), ('vv', '1'), ('vv', '1')]
```

Comment: did you get the dataset where the answer is wrong and the exected outcome?

Comment: @MaartenFabré No, they didn't provide that dataset. Is there any other way to debug?

Comment: @shaikmoeed, Ok, thanks for the edit, I'll look at it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In search of most performant and optimized solution for your task let's consider **3** cases.

We'll test them on input file containing *"example intput"* from the question.

---

Case #**1** - is your initial approach with suggested `sorted` call wrapped in `max_trainset_sorted_counter` function:

```
def max_trainset_sorted_counter():
    with open('lines.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            n = int(line.strip())
            data_set = sorted(tuple(map(str, f.readline().split())) for __ in range(n))
            print(sum(max(Counter(element[1]).values()) for element in groupby(data_set, key=lambda x: x[0])))
```

When profiled (`cProfile`) it produces: ***179*** function calls (165 primitive calls).

---

Case #**2** - is an approach from [previous answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/233109/95789) based on `defaultdict` and `Counter` wrapped in `max_trainset_ddict_counter` function:

```
def max_trainset_ddict_counter():
    with open('lines.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            n = int(line.strip())
            results = defaultdict(Counter)
            data_set = (f.readline().replace('\n', '').split() for _ in range(n))
            for word, result_bool in data_set:
                results[word][result_bool] += 1
            print(sum(max(result_bools.values()) for word, result_bools in results.items()))
```

When profiled it produces: ***140*** function calls.

---

Case #**3** - is actually my solution based on `itertools.groupby`, `itertools.islice` features and simple arithmetic trick of 2 steps to sum up *maximals* (items with greater number of occurrences of `1` or `0` flags) of each group within a *trainset*:

- sum up all values of the group - `sum_ones = sum(int(i[1]) for i in group)`, which actually gives a number of **`1`** values/flags
- then *maximal* is found with simple `max(sum_ones, g_size - sum_ones)`, where `g_size` is assigned with `len(group)` (number of entries within a group). This will cover any combinations of `0` and `1` in *solitary* or mixed sequences.

It's wrapped in `max_trainset_ext_sums` function:

```
def max_trainset_ext_sums():
    with open('lines.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            n = int(line.strip())
            sum_groups = 0
            for k, g in groupby(sorted(tuple(row.split()) for row in islice(f, n)), key=lambda x: x[0]):
                group = tuple(g)
                g_size = len(group)
                if g_size == 1:
                    sum_groups += g_size
                else:
                    sum_ones = sum(int(i[1]) for i in group)
                    sum_groups += max(sum_ones, g_size - sum_ones)
            print(sum_groups)
```

When profiled it produces: ***99*** function calls.

---

All 3 cases produce the same expected output:

```
2
6
3
```

**But** let's get to *time performance* test (note, on very small input sample the time difference may not be significant):

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit('max_trainset_sorted_counter()', setup='from __main__ import max_trainset_sorted_counter', number=1000)
0.1788159019779414
>>> timeit('max_trainset_ddict_counter()', setup='from __main__ import max_trainset_ddict_counter', number=1000)
0.17249802296282724
>>> timeit('max_trainset_ext_sums()', setup='from __main__ import max_trainset_ext_sums', number=1000)
0.14651802799198776
```

Answer (score 2):

On first sight, I see 2 issues:

## `groupby`.

From the documentation:

> The operation of groupby() is similar to the `uniq` filter in Unix. It generates a break or new group every time the value of the key function changes **(which is why it is usually necessary to have sorted the data using the same key function)**.

(emphasis mine)

Compare your result for

```
fck 1
body 0
body 0
fck 0
body 0
ram 0
fck 1
```

to the result for

```
fck 1
fck 0
body 0
body 0
body 0
ram 0
fck 1
```

## debugging

The data structure that is important for the correctness of your answer is:

```
[Counter(element[1]) for element in groupby(data_set, key=lambda x:x[0])]
```

Here you assemble the values, which you later count.

In the first case:

```
[Counter({('fck', '1'): 1, ('fck', '0'): 1}),
 Counter({('body', '0'): 3}),
 Counter({('ram', '0'): 1}),
 Counter({('fck', '1'): 1})]
```

In the second case:

```
[Counter({('fck', '1'): 1}),
 Counter({('body', '0'): 2}),
 Counter({('fck', '0'): 1}),
 Counter({('body', '0'): 1}),
 Counter({('ram', '0'): 1}),
 Counter({('fck', '1'): 1})]
```

The entries for `fck` are not grouped anymore.

The easiest way to solve this, is by changing `data_set` to `data_set = sorted(tuple(map(str, input().split())) for __ in range(n))`,

Or you can use an intermediate 2-level dict, but that is more complicated. I don't know which one will be the fastest.

--

## alternative without `sorted`

You can use `defaultdict` and `Counter` to set up an alternative datastructure

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

input_str = """
fck 1
body 0
body 0
fck 0
body 0
ram 0
fck 1
"""
results = defaultdict(Counter)

data_set = (row.split() for row in input_str.split("\n") if row)
for word, result_bool in data_set:
    results[word][result_bool] += 1
```

> ```
> defaultdict(collections.Counter,
>             {'fck': Counter({'1': 2, '0': 1}),
>              'body': Counter({'0': 3}),
>              'ram': Counter({'0': 1})})
> ```

```
sum(max(result_bools.values()) for word, result_bools in results.items())
```

This does not need the sorting.

Comment: @shaikmoeed Considering there are 2 for loops in your code, probably not.

Comment: @Mast Thanks for letting me know. Can we solve this problem in `O(N)`? or What is the optimal time complexity we can achieve for this problem?

Comment: The outer loop loops over the test cases, so I wouldn't include that in the time complexity analysis. The sorted is `O(n log(n))` (depending on the sortedness of the input), the alternative solution loops once over all the lines, once over all the words, so looks `O(n)` to me